# Why is my variable empty outside of a code block?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Alright so here is my code:

```
var locationCount: Int!
var latLocation = [Double]()
var longLocation = [Double]()

func polyline() {
    var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

    databaseHandle = databaseRef.child("RunList").child(runName).child("locations").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.locationCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(self.locationCount)


        func getLocations()     {

            var i = 0
            while i < self.locationCount {

                self.databaseHandle = self.databaseRef.child("RunList").child(self.runName).child("locations").child("\(i)").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    let locData = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let lat = (locData?["lat"] as? Double)!
                    let long = (locData?["long"] as? Double)!
                    self.latLocation.append(lat)
                    self.longLocation.append(long)
                })

                i = i + 1
            }


        }

    getLocations()

    })

}
```

So the problem I am facing is that when I try to call the two arrays latLocation and longLocation outside of the code blocks/polyline(), they return as empty. So for example, if I try to print them in viewDidLoad(), they both print as empty arrays. How can I fix this? The same issue is with locationCount too, if I print that outside of the code blocks then I get an error where the value is nil because it has no value, but inside of the code block it works perfectly fine. This is really confusing me and I think there is a simple solution to it that I have overlooked.

Comment: Are you sure that the closure has been called before accessing the two arrays? you can check that by adding breakpoints...

Comment: Yes, I run polyline() before accessing the arrays.

Comment: check one more time. polyLine() is run on different thread thats for sure. Thats why you are getting empty array. Print your array after while loop. They must contain value there

Comment: I've tried and it's empty. Basically, the array(s) are empty anywhere outside of the code block where the values are being added to it.

Comment: Once again – as mentioned earlier – learn to understand the behavior of asynchronous tasks. All `observe` methods work asynchronously. The variables are never updated in the enclosing method but – in terms of computer speed – much much later. If you're using a loop where each iteration calls an asynchronous task use `DispatchGroup` to be able to inform the caller when the last iteration finished